# Get the value from a dynamic input element

Tags: jquery

In a web page we have an input type text:

```
<input id="bar" type="text" />
```

I want to insert before another input element before the above element:

```
var input = $('<input type="text" value="foo" id="ciccia" />')
input.insertBefore($('#bar'))
```

And add a simple behavior:

```
input.on('keyup', function(){
    console.log(input.attr('value'));
})
```

console.log always get "foo" string

---

If I change

```
 var input = $('<input type="text" value="foo" id="ciccia" />')
```

to

```
 var input = $('<input type="text" value="bar" id="ciccia" />')
```

console.log always get "bar" string.

---

What's wrong with DOM? Why I cannot read the real value of text input?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use `.val()` to retrieve the text box value, since `.attr('value')` will always return the value which was set in the beginning.

```
input.on('keyup', function(){
    console.log(input.val());
});
```

or simply use `this.value` instead of `input.val()`

Answer (score 1):

`attr` will always return the value which was initially set. You need to use `.value` property

Use

```
input.on('keyup', function(){
    console.log(this.value);
})
```